# Is it possible to connect Adobe Flash CS to Database of any kind?

Tags: database, flash, actionscript

Can I build flash application that connects to database? (MySQL)
For example: Photo Gallery that brings me the photos from database...
             Or Music Player...

Maybe PHP? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) is a technology that allows a Flash app to execute remote code.  Server side implementations exist for a number of server side environments and languages, check out the list in the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: yes.

As fvu mentioned, you can get into AMF which is an excellent choice for heavy lifting, but it's not required.

Using combinations of [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html), [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html) it is very easy to send and receive data in HTTP requests, which then frees you to employ whatever server-side solution you prefer.  The data format you choose is then also up to you; Flash natively supports XML, and full JSON support is found in [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Adobe FlashBuilder (formerly FlexBuilder) is something that would interest you.